# JFoenix JFXTreeTableView styles not working

Tags: java, javafx, jfoenix

I am trying out JavaFX and I used [JFoenix](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix) library to incorporate material design in the application.

All the other controls I added from JFoenix has the material look, but `JFXTreeTableView` does not have the material look shown in the project github page. The table looks the same as the default JavaFX `TableView`.

Following is a screenshot of the `JFXTreeTableView` in my app.

[image]

I have my own stylesheet added to the root node of the scene. It does not seem to have any impact to this issue since when I remove the custom stylesheet, the look of the `JFXTreeTableView` doesn't change.

Does anyone has any clue why the styles aren't applied?

Answer (score 1):

Within [JFoenix Demo application](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/blob/6729cc344533cb51c5acdd2bd87e827cbc2868e9/demo/src/main/java/demos/components/TreeTableDemo.java),

[custom stylesheet for JFXTreeTableView](https://github.com/jfoenixadmin/JFoenix/blob/6729cc344533cb51c5acdd2bd87e827cbc2868e9/demo/src/main/resources/css/jfoenix-main-demo.css) is contained and applied like this.

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(TreeTableDemo.class.getResource("/css/jfoenix-components.css").toExternalForm());
```

[image]

Applying to the root node also works.

```
scene.getRoot().getStylesheets().add(TreeTableDemo.class.getResource("/css/jfoenix-components.css").toExternalForm());
```

If your way was different, try it out please.